# How to make higher order functions synchronous kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to run a test in which I want to wait till higher order function executes. As of now I am not able to figure out any ways to do it. Following is my code.

```kotlin
@Test
    fun `test execute routine error`() = runBlocking(coroutineDispatcher) {
        val observer = mock<Observer<String>>()
        baseViewModel.error.observeForever(observer)
        val httpException = HttpException(Response.error<String>(402, mock(ResponseBody::class.java)))
        val function = baseViewModel.executeRoutine {
            throw httpException
        }
        verify(observer).onChanged("Something went wrong. Please try again")
    }
```

The problem with above snippet is that it jumps to the last line i.e. verify() before throwing an http exception for executeRoutine.

**Update**: Execute routine definition

```kotlin
fun executeRoutine(requestType: RequestType = RequestType.POST_LOGIN, execute: suspend () -> Unit) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                _spinner.postValue(true)
                try {
                    execute()
                } catch (ex: HttpException) {
                    val errorHandler = errorHandlerFactory.create(requestType)
                    _error.postValue(errorHandler.getErrorMessageFrom(ex))
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    _error.postValue(ex.localizedMessage)
                    Timber.e(ex)
                } finally {
                    _spinner.postValue(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the definition of `baseViewModel.executeRoutine`?

Comment: I have added the definition in the qustion @mightyWOZ

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the higher order function *does* execute, it just doesn't do what you think it does -- its execution is launching the task, not waiting for it to complete.

You will have to solve the problem another way, by either having your test wait until the change is observed, or having the callback complete a barrier to allow the test to proceed (e.g. `completableJob.complete()` at the end of the call back, and `completableJob.join()` waiting before proceeding with the test).

It might also be desirable to rearchitect your code so you don't have to do anything special, e.g. by making `executeRoutine` a suspend function executing the code rather than launching the code in another scope.

Comment: I had similar thoughts on rearchitecting the code. Thanks

Comment: A relatively simple approach would be to have executeRoutine return the Job returned by launch, so you could track it and suspend waiting for it.